# KendoMobile ui template not rendering css How to make the template render with kendo stylng in view?

Tags: kendo-ui

Basically the template wont render to a ScrollView using `kendo.render(template, response)` but WILL work with `content = template(response)` - BUT this has no styling in view -- see comment below

How to make the template render with kendo stylign in view?

BTW response from api call is JSON:

{"event_id":"5","stamp":"2013-01-24 06:00:00","type":"Event Type","loc":"Location","status":"1"}

```
<!-- eventDetail view -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div data-role="view" id="view-eventDetail" data-show="getEventDetailData" data-title="eventDetail">
        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <span data-role="view-title"></span>
                <a data-align="right" data-role="button" class="nav-button" href="#view-myEvents">Back</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="eventDetail" data-role="page"></div>
    </div>

    <script id="eventDetail-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        --><form id="addEventForm"><p>
        <input name="event_type" id="event_type" data-min="true" type="text" value="#= type #" />
        </p>
        <p>         
        <input name="event_loc" id="event_loc" data-min="true" type="text" value="#= loc #" />
        </p>
        <p>         
        <input name="event_date_time" id="event_date_time" data-min="true" type="datetime" value="#= stamp#" />
        </p>
        <p>
        Share this
        <input data-role="switch" id="event_share" data-min="true" checked="checked" value="1"/></p>
        <p>
        <input type="button" id="eventCancelButton" style="width:30%" data-role="button" data-min="true" value="Cancel" />
        <input type="submit" id="eventDoneButton" style="width:30%" data-role="button"  data-min="true" value="Done" />
        </p></form><!--
    </script>

    <script>

        //eventDetail engine
        function getEventDetailData(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/mpt/website/api/event_details.php?',
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { userID: 2, eventID: e.view.params.id },


                success: function(response) {

                    console.log(response);

                    var template = kendo.template($("#eventDetail-template").html()),
                    content = template(response);//works but no kendo css
                    //content = kendo.render(template, response);not working

                    $("#eventDetail")
                    .kendoMobileScrollView()
                    .data("kendoMobileScrollView")
                    .content("<!--" + content + "-->");
                }
            });
        }</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widget classes (like `km-button`) are not added until the widget is initialized.

The `template()` and `render()` functions just return the template as a string with the data replaced (replaces #=foo# with the value of the foo property) but does not init all the widgets. In fact, it coldn't initialize the widgets if it wanted to singe it just returns a text string, not DOM elements. The initialization of the widgets is usually done by the parent widget that is using the template.

---

`render()` is not working in your case because its 2nd argument is supposed to be an array. All it does is call the given template function once per item in the array and concatenate the results. If you instead did:

```
var content = kendo.render(template, [response]); // wrap response in an array
```

it would return the same text string as `template(response)`. It just provides a way to apply the same template to many items at once.

---

Normally when you create a widget, in your case calling `.kendoMobileScrollView()` you would expect it to turn any HTML contents of that element into widgets too, but it looks like the ScrollView widget doesn't do this. I think its intent may have been to just display pages of static content, not other widgets.

---

There is a Kendo method that isn't listed in the docs, `kendo.mobile.init(contents);` that you might be able to use to turn your template string into widgets. When I tried it in a jsFiddle it threw some error for me, but you could try something like:

```
var content = template(response); // apply response to template
var contentElements = $(content); // turn the string into DOM elements
kendo.mobile.init(contentElements); // turn elements into widgets (this throws error for me)
$("#eventDetail").html(contentElements); // add contents to the desired element
$("#eventDetail").kendoMobileScrollView(); // create the scroll view
```

---

Also, what is with the end and begin comment bits hanging off the ends of the template? I don't see why those are needed. Might be better to remove them.

---

The ScrollView widget is supposed to take a series of `<div>` elements as its children. It then pages between them as you swipe left/right across the control. I don't see you adding a series of `<div>`s anywhere.

Comment: The begin comments tags are from the docs - removes white spaces that may cause issues with the ScrollView widget.  Overall you solved my issue thx

Comment: OK so i switched to a listview - but still no luck.. see my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389522/kendo-mobile-template-styling-formatting-not-working