# Kendo mobile template styling/formatting not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to use a template as shown below, the outcome is a view with all elements from the template on one line, even though i am using

to separate the elements. Why does this not display properly? It seems that no matter what styling i do it still ends up a single line view.

UPDATE
The culprit is the kendo style sheet - kendo.mobile.all.min.css -

So the new question for a kendo expert is why does kendo handle input fields differently when they appear in a listview via a template than when they appear outside of a template?

An input field outside of a listview template gets this class

```
.km-ios .km-list input:not([type="button"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"]):not([type="image"]):not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]):not(.k-input):not(.k-button), .km-ios .km-list select:not([multiple]), .km-ios .km-list .k-dropdown-wrap, .km-ios .km-list textarea
```

Which results in no odd styling rules :) Normal text field view

An input field inside of the template gets this class

```
.km-root input:not([type="button"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"]):not([type="image"]):not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]):not(.k-input):not(.k-button), .km-root select:not([multiple]), .km-root .k-dropdown, .km-root textarea
```

which results in these rules being applied to it (making the field sit in a wierd spot and loose all normal field stlying ie border background etc.) Im not 100% sure which wrapper is causing this

```
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
font-size: 1.1rem;
color: #385487;
min-width: 6em;
border: 0;
padding: .4em;
outline: 0;
background: 
transparent;
```

My work around is to give any text fields inside listview templates the class="k-input" which obviously excludes them from the above css -

```
<script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>



    <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- eventDetail view -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div data-role="view" id="view-eventDetail" data-show="getEventDetailData" data-title="eventDetail">
        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <span data-role="view-title"></span>
                <a data-align="right" data-role="button" class="nav-button" href="#view-myEvents">Back</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <form id="updateEventForm">
            <div id="updateEvent">
                <div id="eventDetail"></div>
                <p>
                    <input type="button" id="eventUpdateCancelButton" style="width:30%" data-role="button" data-min="true" value="Back" />
                    <input type="submit" id="eventUpdateSaveButton" style="width:30%" data-role="button"  data-min="true" value="Save" />
                </p>
                <div id="eventResult"></div>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

    <script id="eventDetail-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">

        <p>
        <input name="event_type" id="event_type" data-min="true" type="text" value="#= type #" />
        </p>
        <p>

        <input name="event_loc" id="event_loc" data-min="true" type="text" value="#= type #" />
        </p>
        <p>

        <input name="event_date_time" id="event_date_time" data-min="true" type="datetime" value="#= stamp #" />
        </p>
        <p>
        Share this
        <input data-role="switch" id="event_share" data-min="true" checked="checked" value="#= share #"/>
        </p>
        <input name="userID" id="userID" type="hidden" value="#= user_id #" />
        <input name="eventID" id="eventID" type="hidden" value="#= event_id #" />

    </script>

    <script>        
        function getEventDetailData(e) {

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://localhost/mpt/website/api/event_details.php",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { userID: e.view.params.user_id, eventID: e.view.params.event_id },
                        cache: false
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(options) {
                        return {
                            userID: options.userID,
                            eventID: options.eventID

                        };
                    }
                },
                schema: { // describe the result format
                    data: "results" // the data which the data source will be bound to is in the "results" field
                }
            });           

            console.log(e);

            $("#eventDetail").kendoMobileListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: kendo.template($("#eventDetail-template").html())

            }).data("kendoMobileListView");

        }           

        //update event          
        function sendUpdateEvent() {

            var siteURI = "http://localhost/mpt/website/api/update_event.php?";

            app.showLoading();

            var user_id = $('#userID').val();
            var event_id = $('#eventID').val();
            var event_type = $('#event_type').val();
            var event_loc = $('#event_loc').val();
            var event_date_time = $('#event_date_time').val();
            var event_share = $('#event_share').val();

            var formVals = 'eventID=' + event_id + '&userID=' + user_id + '&event_type=' + event_type + '&event_loc=' + event_loc + '&event_date_time=' + event_date_time + '&event_share=' + event_share;
            var fullURI = siteURI + formVals;

            $.ajax({
                url: fullURI, dataType: 'json', success: function (data) {
                    $('#eventResult').html(data.results);
                    app.hideLoading();
                    app.navigate("#view-myEvents");

                }
            });
        }

        $('#eventUpdateCancelButton').click(function () {

            app.navigate("#view-myEvents");
        });

        $('#eventUpdateSaveButton').click(function () {

            sendUpdateEvent();
        });

        $('#updateEventForm').submit(function () {

            sendUpdateEvent();

            return false;
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView widgets are supposed to be applied to `<ul>` elements.
Try changing:

```
<div id="eventDetail"></div>
```

to:

```
<ul id="eventDetail"></ul>
```

---

Also with this bit of code:

```
        $("#eventDetail").kendoMobileListView({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            template: kendo.template($("#eventDetail-template").html())
        }).data("kendoMobileListView");
```

The `.data()` call on the end isn't doing anything here and can be removed, and also you can pass just the text string as the template. You don't need to call `kendo.template()` yourself. So you can change that to just:

```
        $("#eventDetail").kendoMobileListView({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            template: $("#eventDetail-template").html()
        });
```

Comment: Listview can be used with a div - http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/howto-use-the-listview-of-kendo-ui-web - most importantly see my answer below - it seems kendo handles form elements differently when they are part of a template :)

Comment: Listview can be used with a div - http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/howto-use-the-listview-of-kendo-ui-web - most importantly link below - it seems kendo handles form elements differently when they are part of a template :) - BUT i can add a text field to this fiddle with no issues? http://jsfiddle.net/jbristowe/3w7ru/light/ - is it styling?

Comment: When I tried `.kendoMobileListView()` against a `<div>` it generated the HTML `<div> <li></li> <li></li> </div>` instead of automatically putting in a `<ul>` element, but maybe I had just messed something up in my jsFiddle when I tried it. Sorry!

Comment: No worries - heres the jist - when running the code above in a Non-Kendo environment - all styling is fine :) - Im not sure what exactly is causing the styling issue - BUT if i remove the kendo style sheet kendo.mobile.all.min.css from my project - wammo - styling is as expected ...i am going to research a little more but it appears kendo style sheet does NOT handle the template in the same way it handles a straight view

Comment: @DropHit KendoUI have two *different* widgets with name ListView. Mobile ListView is different from Web ListView.
As CodingWithSpike said the Mobile ListView should be build from <ul> element. You may check the respective help article: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/listview

Comment: MobileListView is used OUTSIDE of UL all over the kendo mobile wesbites inside a div etc... also not sure what the comment does to help solve my problem?